# Why aren't OOP design patterns included in the standard libraries?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, dry

I have a question similar to this other question

[Why aren't design patterns added to the languages constructs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157181/why-arent-design-patterns-added-to-the-languages-constructs)

Why isn't there `java.util.Singleton` and then we inherit it? The boilerplate code seems to be always the same.

```
class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton s = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return s;
    }

    protected Singleton() {
    }
}

class XSingleton extends Singleton {

}
```

Now if there was a `Singleton` built-in to Java then we wouldn't have to include the same boiler-plate over and over in projects. We could just inherit the code that makes the Singleton and just code our specific in our `XSingleton` that `extends Singleton`.

I suppose the same goes for other design patterns e.g. MVC and similar. Why aren't more design pattern built into the standard libraries?

Comment: Ignoring that people don't really like singletons; most of that seems to achieve nothing. If you are going to use singletons (usually not a good idea) why not just access it as `Singleton.s`

Comment: Design patterns would be added to standard libraries if they were like Tinkertoys that you could assemble in different ways to make programs.  Fortunately, they're not.

Comment: OK, let's run with the premise of your question. I have a Frobulator. There's only one of them. How do I make a singleton Frobulator using your base class? If it is so easy then you should be able to write the code in a comment. Bonus: once you've done that: did I mention that Frobulator extends Blobulator, and Blobulator is *not* a singleton?  Now how would you write the code to make a singleton Frobulator?

Comment: For a more complex example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951818/why-can-the-monad-interface-not-be-declared-in-java/35959910#35959910, where I describe why the "monad" design pattern cannot have a type in Java or C#. What you should be taking away from the monad and singleton examples is: *design patterns need to be invented because type systems are insufficiently powerful to describe the pattern*.

Comment: @EricLippert Maybe the Singleton could be an interface so that `class Frobulator extends Blobulator implements Singleton {}` ? I agree with the conclusion that (most of) our patterns can't be described with types. `java.Math` doesn't even have a `class Matrix` so we reinvent the wheel and break the DRY principle. It's interesting to compare a type and a pattern. If a pattern is very easy then it could be described and reused as a type. I suppose a design pattern is more similar to a use case than it is similar to a type. I also see the `class User` reinvented in every project.

Comment: @DacSaunders: The purpose of an interface is to capture the notion of *common functionality independent of implementation*.  What common functionality independent of implementation would you like to capture for the notion of "singleton"?  Can you describe a method that takes only instances of singletons?  Here, I have a singleton task scheduler, a singleton string pool, and a singleton vampire-attack-resolution-rulebook.  What useful method takes those, and *only* those things?

Comment: If there is no method in the world that can reasonably have the signature `void DoSomethingUseful(Singleton s)` then there is no *incentive* to developers to make their singleton types implement that interface. Contrast that with a pattern that *is* embedded in the language, such as "non-local goto for error handling".  There *is* an incentive for developers to participate in the exception pattern by inheriting from its base class because doing so buys them a useful feature. And there *are* useful methods that take exceptions.

Comment: FWIW, I had a manager at a past job who wanted to do exactly this -- implement basic patterns and then *pay-license the library* to other software companies.

Comment: @EricLippert A singleton was a bad example and I don't have a resource to motivate. But common functionality could be such as cross-cutting concerns e.g. logging, security, privacy or also objects that don't exist in the system but need a representation anyhow. Also some systems have a "king", a "dictator" or just one "owner" or a founder. I wish I had used another example than a singleton. I'm also trying to learn why some patterns become part of a standard library and some patterns don't in order to make my own language and what to include in a minimal language according to DRY principle.

Comment: @insta Yes, why are there so few choices of test frameworks in Java and what takes so long to include basic `java.util.logging` where the latter is often not prefereed and neither of those were included in the standard library in the early Java releases even though almost all mature projects use tests and logging. Instead we got `EJB` and `JSP` that solved very specific problems for only a few specialized projects. I'm trying to understand the decisions behind what get included in a programming language and who doesn't get included and programmers must make themselves. There is no `class User`

Comment: @DacSaunders: The patterns that are in standard libraries are precisely those which are easy to add to libraries. Patterns like "queue" or "search tree" are amenable to that treatment.  "Visitor" is not.

Comment: @DacSaunders: Why is a "minimal" language desirable? Combinatory logic, Turing machines and Lambda calculus are all equally powerful minimalist approaches to computation; they don't even have patterns like "integer" or "string". There has been a lot of academic research on minimal languages; if you're interested in truly minimal languages I would  start by looking at those.

Comment: @EricLippert I will study Lambda calculus so that I know what I'm talking about. I want to learn the decisions on what must work in order to meet the requirements for a "minimal language". My goal is to design a language but I don't know the formal requirements for language and new types built by the minimal types. I want to learn language design and write a grammar. I'm writing a grammar. I have succeeded writing the grammar for conditional statement and loop using the Lemon Parser and C so that it can read and run a small program. It's fun but I can't do an `else` yet.

Comment: @DacSaunders: I am in the middle of a long series on my blog on dissecting a 40 year old seminal paper on type analysis in a minimal language based on lambda calculus. You might find it interesting.

Comment: @EricLippert I will follow!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I want to challenge your basic premise, namely that Design Patterns aren't added to the standard library. For example, [`java.util.Iterator<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is in the standard library and is an implementation of the [Iterator Design Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?IteratorPattern). [`java.util.Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)/[`java.util.Observer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) is an implementation of the [Publish/Subscribe Design Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ObserverPattern). [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) is an implementation of the [Proxy Design Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ProxyPattern).

Looking at other languages, e.g. Ruby has the [`delegate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/) and [`forwardable`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/) libraries, both implementations of the Proxy Design Pattern, the [`observer`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/observer/rdoc/) library, an implementation of the Publish/Subscribe Pattern, and the [`singleton`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/) library, an implementation of the [Singleton Design Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?SingletonPattern).

Answer (score 24):

Design patterns are recurring designs which cannot be captured in a class or library. Usually they have to do with how multiple classes interact. The standard library of a language can *use* patterns just like other code can - eg. the Java IO library uses the decorator pattern. But the decorator pattern itself cannot be captured in a single class or library.

A typical definition of design patter (taken from Wikipedia):

> In software engineering, a software design pattern is a general
>   reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given
>   context in software design. **It is not a finished design that can be
>   transformed directly into source or machine code.** It is a
>   description or template for how to solve a problem that can be used in
>   many different situations.

(My emphasis) So by definition a standard library cannot provide design patterns as reusable components the same way it provides regular classes as reusable component. Or to put it another way: If some design pattern *can* be captured in reusable code, we stop calling it a pattern. `List<T>` is a broadly useful design, but since this can be captured in a reusable class, we don't usually call it a "pattern" - it is just a class.

But a framework can *encourage* and to some extent *enforce* the use of certain design patterns. Eg. a MVC framework more or less forces you to write code following the MVC pattern.

There are different reasons why patterns cannot be captured as a reusable class, depending on the pattern:

1. The pattern is is too abstract. E.g. an "Adapter" is a pattern where a class
   transforms one interface to another. The concept is pretty simple,
   but the actual implementation will be fully dependent on the semantics of the two
   interfaces in actuation. There is simply no shared boilerplate code
   between different application of the Adapter pattern, so it cannot
   be included as a reusable component in a library.
2. The pattern is not possible to implement in a reusable form. Some patterns
   are really workaround for language limitations. E.g. the "Visitor"
   pattern is really a hack to allow a single-dispatch language to
   support multiple dispatch. There is some boilerplate code, but the
   boilerplate code cannot be generalized in a reusable way. A language
   with built-in support for multiple dispatch would not need the
   visitor pattern in the first place.

   (And as pointed out in several comments, the Singleton implementation you provide cannot be generalized to a reusable class, since statics are not inherited.)

Comment: and we can't inherits static aniway it will be one instance for all that inherits ;D

Comment: might be worth pointing out the interplay between different languages i.e. what is a pattern in one language could be a language/library feature in another

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand your point, and your answer looks much better now. Changed my downvote into an upvote. I see it is debatable if the cases mentioned by JörgWMittag are really "pattern implementations", or if they are just help to implement them for a user of the Java standard lib.

Comment: "Or to put it another way: If some design pattern can be captured in reusable code, we stop calling it a pattern." -- I'm not sure this is really true.  Consider Iterator; it is clear that the pattern can be captured using reusable OO code, as this is done in the standard libraries of many languages.  Nobody has stopped calling it a pattern, though.  I think we call it a pattern because we *need to be able to talk about it at a higher level than implementation details* in order to discuss how it relates to other code, and whether it's implemented by the developer or the language is irrelevant.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta: we only call the iterator a design pattern now in an academic sense, because its in the GoF book. In the days of all assembly, functions could be considered a pattern, frequently implemented in a particular way. We don't generally call functions a design pattern now because it's so commonplace and integral to programming today. Iterators are similar now, they weren't so much in 1994

Comment: "A typical definition of design patter" ... is missing an 'n'.

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer. JörgWMittag's answer just says "it's not true".

Answer (score 5):

I fear a subtlety of the word "pattern" is being lost here. Think of a suit. A pattern defines the features - e.g. there are pockets, arms, legs etc. However, it doesn't define every single detail (buttons, fabric, lining etc) - this is left to the implementer.

Yes, for a lot of design patterns there is boilerplate code many of us tend to use, but for others, there is more than one way of achieving the pattern with no generally agreed method.

Comment: Fabric patterns usually do indicate how things are put together, they specify stitch types, notion placement and other details. Come to think of it, since the choice of fabrics and colors etc is left to the tailor, fabric patterns pretty much describe exclusively *how* to put a garment together.  Might wanna pick a different analogy.

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't there java.util.Singleton and then we inherit it?

Because a singleton is `static` and we can't use inheritance on `static` members. Also, it's considered better practice to declare a Singleton using an enum:

```
public enum MySingleton{
    INSTANCE;

    //class content goes below
}
```

It would also be hard to use inheritance here as an `enum` extends `java.lang.Enum` and that cannot be changed, and there is no way to remove the 1 line of boilerplate code.

This is why `java.util.Singleton` doesn't exist.

---

> Why aren't design patterns added to the languages constructs?

Quite a lot are already in the jdk standard library - quite a few classes provide some functionality when using patterns, for example: `java.util.Observer` is implemented when using the Observer patterns and others utilize design patterns, for example: `java.lang.StringBuilder` utilizes the Builder pattern.

As for why you don't see them all:

- Some design patterns are hard to abstract away with classes/interfaces/enums/ect (`java.util.Singleton` for example).
- It's not worth putting in the standard library.
- It hasn't been thought of yet.
- There is no need for it.

Comment: The first half of this answer is a rather specific limitation of the particular language and pattern chosen as an example. Plenty of languages do have the necessary machinery to implement a Singleton base class, and Java happens not to; but that doesn't really tell us much about the relationship between patterns and language features.